# How do i access session in lib classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I am developing an application in rails 3

How do i access session in lib classes in Rails.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in Rails, `ApplicationController` has a method named `session`, use `session[:user_id]` to fetch the session value. Thus, if you want use session in lib, you need define a method in lib classes which access session as parameter.

**lib/your_class.rb**

```
class YourClass

  def set_session(session_)
    @mysession = session_ 
  end

  def session
    return @mysession
  end

end
```

The simple way is that, you can use module instead of lib class, and include the module in your Controller. Then you can use `session[:user_id]` in the lib module any way.